# Unable to install GridDB on Open Suse

Tags: opensuse, griddb

I am trying to install GridDB on Open Suse as it was not working on Fedora. When I run the command $ ./bootstrap.sh as mentioned in the help doc (https://docs.griddb.net/gettingstarted/using-source-code/) it gives the following error.

[error while running the command ./bootstrap.sh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBKZ0.png)

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to install `automake`, `autoconf` and `libtool` before you initiate the configuration for gridDB.
In case you've got zypper as the package manager:

```
zypper install libtool automake autoconf
```

Also, as a note of heads up, the document that you're following has been tested and verified on Centos 7:

```
We have confirmed the operation on CentOS 7.6 (gcc 4.8.5).
```

You might face a few surprises like these. Happy to help on the way.

**Edit 1:**

For those who do not have an appropriate C compiler installed:

```
zypper install gcc48
```

Comment: Thanks, I am now able to run the command but during execution, it's all giving the warning. Is that fine to ignore the warnings?

and when I run the command ./configure its gives error at the end that no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH.

Comment: Would be great if you could post the full log of the installation by editing your question. Also, about the missing C compiler, it indicates that your system is missing gcc/g++ to compile the code.

Comment: Updated answer to provide C compiler installation step.